# Silly question? How do I see data-blocks menu in 2.80?

Tags: objects

As subject.  The docs mention what to do when you find the menu - but I am unable to find it!

Thanks.

Comment: what menu are you talking about? The data-blocks appear in the Outliner editor, which is the top right window by default in 2.8. In one of the dropdown menu of this window you need to choose View Layer which should also be here by default

Comment: The one described in the Blender Manual at:https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/templates/data_block.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had a bit of trouble locating it at first as well.

Here's how:
Open an outliner and then change the outliner type using the second dropdown from the left. Select blend file

[image: outliner mode selection]

[image: Blend file outliner]

This blend file outliner has all of your data block objects. Here you can perform useful operations such as duplicating and unlinking them.